# how to substring string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have filenames like below:

```
PRJ25 Sample1 Siver_Output_Log_2020_11_10_13.csv
PRJ25 Sample1 Siver_Output_Log_2020_12_30_4_1.csv
PRJ25 Sample1 Siver_Output_Log_2021_1_8_4.csv
```

I want output to `year, month, day` from these filenames. I tried below code but filename is not consistent so i am unable to get these values, expected result:

```
year : 2020 or 2021
month: 11 or 12 or 1
day: 10 or 30 or 8
```

My code:

```
year = file_name[len(file_name) - 14:len(file_name) - 10]
    month = file_name[len(file_name) - 9:len(file_name) - 8]
    day = file_name[len(file_name) - 7:len(file_name) - 6]
```

Comment: `.split('_',3)[-1].split('.')[0].split('_')`

Comment: "I tried below code but filename is not consistent " I don't understand what this means. You should show an example of a filename where it *doesn't* work, show what happens, show what is supposed to happen, and explain what you think is going wrong.

Comment: "I want output to retrieve year,month,day from these filenames" Okay. What is the **actual rule** that tells you where the year, month and day are contained in the string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
files = [
    "PRJ25 Sample1 Siver_Output_Log_2020_11_10_13.csv",
    "PRJ25 Sample1 Siver_Output_Log_2020_12_30_4_1.csv",
    "PRJ25 Sample1 Siver_Output_Log_2021_1_8_4.csv",
]

results = [f.split("Log_")[-1].rsplit("_")[:3] for f in files]

print(results)

for result in results:
    year, month, day = result
    print(year, month, day)
    # do your stuff here
```

Output:

```
[['2020', '11', '10'], ['2020', '12', '30'], ['2021', '1', '8']]
2020 11 10
2020 12 30
2021 1 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function :

```
year = file_name.split('_')[3]
```

Split transforms your string in a list of strings separated by the character you specified. For year I retrieve the 4th one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
year, month, day, last_num = filename.split("_")[-4:]
last_num = last_num.split(".")[0]
```